# Trying to limit max requests for Facebook App

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

i'm working with FB.ui and trying to limit my max invites for users.  I used the max_recipients parameter, but after sending the initial max invites, let's say 5, the user can still invite more people.  it seems that it only limits the number of requests a user can send at one time, and not the maximum requests over all. did I misunderstand how max_recipients works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how it works - if you want to stop the user sending more than X requests per day, stop showing them the option to do so - track the requests they send using the callback from the Requests dialog and keep a counter in your own code